# Android- I have two Fragments and i want to show output of one, on another Activity.

Tags: android, database, listview, android-studio

I am facing little problem... I have 2 `Fragments` in `AndroidStudio`. Each `Fragment` consist of `ListViews`. I already filled these `Listviews` with the help of `QUERY` from DataBase. Now what i want to do is that when i click on the first`listView` (Fragment) items, then it should take me to another `RESULT Activity` or when i click on the second `Listvew`(fragment) items then it should take me to again on `RESULT Activity` but with the result of second `ListView` it means i have only one `Activity` to show results of two `Fragments`. All these steps should be happen with the help of `Query`. I am trying but My`RESULT Activity` running only one `Query` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulties understanding your question. Can you provide further explanation? So far I got that the situation is:

[image]

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out sending a tag that determines which list was clicked instead of sending data from db to activity.And then can inflate the data from db in that activity.